# how to apply cssClass on custom LoadingController

Tags: angular, sass, ionic2, loading

According to this http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/loading/LoadingController/ i can apply `cssClass` to loadingCtrl.

this is my funtion

```
presentLoadingCustom() {
    this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      spinner: 'hide',
      content: `
        <img src="assets/images/loader/loading.gif" class="img-align" />
        `,
      cssClass:`
      //below class in inbuilt class 
       .loading-wrapper{
        background:none;
        box-shadow: none;
      }
      .img-align{
        height:80px;
      }`
    });
    this.loading.present();
  }
```

i am not able to see my loader after i applied the cssClass but i need this two class to be applied to my custom image loader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/loading/LoadingController/#advanced) `cssClass` option accepts `classes for custom styles, separated by spaces` only not the way you have passed css to it. so change your `presentLoadingCustom` function as below :

```
presentLoadingCustom() {
  this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
    spinner: 'hide',
    content: `<img src="assets/images/loader/loading.gif" class="img-align" />`,
    cssClass:`loading-wrapper img-align`
  });

  this.loading.present();
}
```

You have to add your `loading-wrapper` and `img-align` classes style definitation into your css file not in `create` method of `LoadingController`.

Comment: loading-wrapper and img-align class where i have to write now

Comment: in your application's stylesheet file

Comment: i am using providers so i dont have @component inside the providers so where i will be able to place this css class

Comment: You can create new css file and include it in your HTML with correct path or you can add both class inside your main component (let say AppComponent)  css and try to check if its working or not.

Answer (score 0):

I was having same problem... but the correct way to set this CSS for loadingController is through the example below

```
async presentLoadingWithOptions() {
    const loading = await this.loadingController.create({

      duration: 55000,
      message: '<div><img src="../assets/imgs/plane_loading.gif" class="img-align"  /> <br />...Please wait</div>',
      spinner: null, 
      translucent: true,

      cssClass:'custom-loader-class',
      backdropDismiss: true
    });
    await loading.present();

    const { role, data } = await loading.onDidDismiss();
    console.log('Loading dismissed with role:', role);
  }
```

Than u need to go to global.css and add the following for example

```
.custom-loader-class{
    --background:#F4B004;
    --spinner-color:#F94701;
}
```